# Showing this iterative ODE solver converges quadratically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Given the ODE:

$$y'(t) = f(y(t)), y(0) = y_0,$$

And the following method to solve the ODE:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n +\frac{h}{2}(f(y_n)+f(y_n+hf(y_n))),$$

I am trying to show the method converges quadratically.

I looked at the error at a time $t_n=hn$ which I denoted as $e_n = |y_n-y(t_n)|$ and then tried to find $p>0$ s.t. :

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^p}=\lambda$$

for some $\lambda>0,$

but I ran into the problem in the calculation that is: how do I use $y(t_n)$, or at least simplify it or manipulate it to make it useful for finding such a $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [Heun's (2nd order) method](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bode%5D+heun+error), you will find more details. What quadratic or second order convergence means for ODE solutions is that the error of the numerical solution against the exact solution is $O(h^2)$, which is different from quadratic convergence for the Newton method.

Or more precisely, let $y(t)$ be the exact solution for the IVP with $y(t_0)=y_0$ and $y_n\approx y(t_n)$ the numerical solution for step size $h$. Further $L$ the Lipschitz constant of $f$. Then there exists some constant $M\sim \sup_t |y'''(t)|$ so that the individual local truncation errors are bounded by $Mh^3$.

Propagation of previous errors happens at a rate bounded by the Lipschitz constant $L$, giving an error propagation inequality of $$e_{n+1}\le(1+Lh)e_n+Mh^3,$$ which solves to 
$$
e_n=|y_n-y(t_n)|\le \frac{e^{L|t_n-t_0|}-1}L\cdot Mh^2,
$$
using $(1+Lh)^n\le e^{Lhn}$.

Comment: How did you obtain the RHS of the inequality?

Comment: I added some details that can also be found in the linked search results.